# PowerPoint OOXML: Consistent Placeholder IDs Across Slide Layouts to Prevent Content Movement

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

## Problem Context

I am working with PowerPoint's OOXML to manage slide layouts. I have a Slide Master with 20 slide layouts with some having identical placeholders like "Footnotes Placeholder". When I change the slide layout, the content moves to different placeholders, which is undesired.

To fix this, I wrote a script that updates the OOXML of all `slideLayout` files, ensuring the `id` attributes in the `<p:cNvPr>` and `<a16:creationId>` tags are consistent for the same placeholders across all slide layouts.

### Problem

I tested this by creating a new presentation using the updated slide layouts. However, the issue persists - the slides still use the old `id` values from the previous `slideLayout` XML.

Here’s a snippet from the XML of a slide and the corresponding slide layout for the same placeholder which inexplicably different `id` values:

```xml
<!-- slide2.xml -->
<a:extLst>
    <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
        <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main"
                          id="{CAAC20ED-B250-44F0-AB9D-1B914BE47B67}"/>
    </a:ext>
</a:extLst>

<!-- slideLayout15.xml -->
<a:extLst>
    <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
        <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main"
                          id="{60633F84-1E68-4543-AA06-5B2AD012EC52}"/>
    </a:ext>
</a:extLst>
```

I would expect the `id` attribute in the `<a16:creationId>` element to have the same UUID.

I have verified the `id` values in the Slide Layout XML of the `.pptx` are what I am expecting (the updated values from my script), but the Slide XML does not have the same values for the placeholders.

I've tried saving the `.pptx` as a `.thmx` and creating a new presentation for the `.thmx` but the same issue persists.

### Questions

I cannot for the life of me figure out why isn't this behaving as I'd expect.

- Why aren’t the new slides in the new presentation using the updated `id` values for the placeholders in the `<a16:crationId>` element?
- Is there a caching mechanism or some internal mapping within PowerPoint that's overriding the `id` values in the placeholders when creating a slide?
- Is there another place within the PPT OOXML that I need to update the `id` values to match the updated `id` values in the Slide Layout XML files?

Any insights or solutions to ensure consistent placeholder identification across slide layouts would be greatly appreciated!

#### *Process to Update Slide Layouts XML*

If it's relevant to the issue at hand, here's the high-level process for how my script updates the `id` values in the Slide Layout XML.

1. Change the `.pptx` extension to `.zip`
2. Extract all `.xml` files from `ppt\slideLayouts` within the ZIP to a local directory.
3. Extract Placeholder Information from a Slide Layout XML:

   - Find all the `<p:sp>` elements in the XML that represent placeholders.
   - For each placeholder, locate the `<p:cNvPr>` element within it.
   - Extract the `id` and `name` from the `<p:cNvPr>` element and the UUID from `id` attribute in the the `<a16:creationId>` element.
   - Store this information in a list using the `name` attribute as a key.
4. Generate Unique and Consistent IDs for Placeholders:

   - Initialize dictionaries to globally track placeholder IDs of the `<p:cNvPr>` element and and UUIDs in the `<a16:creationId>` element
   - For each placeholder in each XML file:

     - Check if the placeholder name already has an ID assigned in the global ID dictionary.

       - If yes, retrieve and use the existing ID.
       - If no, generate a new unique ID and store it in the dictionary.
     - Similarly, check for the UUID in the global UUID dictionary.

       - If found, use the existing UUID.
       - If not, generate a new UUID and store it.
5. Update the Slide Layout XML with Modified IDs and UUIDs:

   - Locate all `<p:cNvPr>` elements.
   - For each `<p:cNvPr>` element:

     - Retrieve the placeholder name from the `name` attribute in the `<p:cNvPr>` element.
     - If the placeholder name is found in the global ID dictionary:

       - Update the "id" attribute in the XML with the new ID.
       - Also, locate the `<a16:creationId>` element within the current `<p:cNvPr>` element and update its UUID.
   - Save the modified XML back to the file.
6. Replace the Slide Layout XML Files in the ZIP Archive:

   - Check if the file exists in the `ppt\slideLayouts` within the ZIP archive.
   - If it does, delete the file from the ZIP archive.
   - Add the updated Slide Layout XML file to `ppt\slideLayouts` within the ZIP archive.

Then change the extension back to `.pptx`.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'm having a hard time understanding how the issue was created in the first place. Is there a sample file I can download from somewhere in order to investigate?

Comment: Particularly, this line: "When I change the slide layout, the content moves to different placeholders, which is undesired." What does that mean?